# What causes cellular differentiation?

Tags: genetics

Each cell in our body contains identical dna. And, yet some cells become liver cells, some become brain cells etc. How this happens , when all of them has same dna? Is it because of epigenetic control of gene expression?

Comment: This is a **very** broad question. Please start reading a textbook on this topic.

Comment: You can start with [Wikipedia's cellular differentiation article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_differentiation).